# Extraño error al activar una base de datos

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans-8.2

Veran, tengo una tabla llamada Seguro, y tengo otra llamada PersistenciaSeguro, que se encarga de realizar operaciones con los datos en Seguro (insertar, modificar, eliminar, etc).

Para eso, debo importar lo siguiente en PersistenciaSeguro:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
```

Y despues preparo a PersistenciaSeguro:

```
public class PersistenciaSeguro{
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}
```

Sin embargo, observo que me saltan errores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo más extraño es que no me ocurre en la clase principal, de nombre Ejercicio01:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente necesito que se me permita poner ese código en PersistenciaSeguro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes invocar métodos (`configuration.configure()`) ni asignar valores a atributos de la clase (`sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);`) fuera de un método o un contexto estático (excepto si lo haces junto con la definición del atributo de la clase `Configuration configuration = new Configuration();`). En la clase "principal" si te das cuanta todo eso lo estás haciendo dentro de un método, el método `main`, por ese motivo no tienes errores. Para solucionar esto, incluye el código que presenta errores dentro del constructor de la clase.

```
public class PersistenciaSeguro{
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

    public PersistenciaSeguro() {
        configuration.configure();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
}
```

Pero lo más recomendado es que todas las inicializaciones se hagan dentro de los constructores.

```
public class PersistenciaSeguro{
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Configuration configuration;
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public PersistenciaSeguro() {
        configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues ahora si que he dejado de quejarse. ¡Gracias!

Comment: aunque es raro lo que dices de crear metodos estaticos para poder usar estos metodos. ¿Como hago para que una clase sea estatica?

Comment: No, no, lo que te decía era que para inicializar atributos fuera de la declaración de estos, y para invocar métodos fuera de la declaración de los atributos, solo puedes hacerlo dentro de un método, o dentro de un bloque de inicialización estático (lo que tiene algunas restricciones). No entiendo bien para que necesitas una clase estática pero te comparto un [enlace](http://aquiseprograma.co/2016/01/como-declarar-correctamente-una-clase-estatica-en-java/) que te explica muy bien este tema. Aquí tienes [otro](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/la-directiva-static-en-java/)

Comment: @E.Bentazos Lo decia porque por como lo decias dabas a entender que para usar esas variables tenia que estar creando clases static, aunque esos enlaces me ha aclarado que el static es más para herencia de objetos. Por cierto, estoy metido en otro raro apuro (en otra pregunta). A ver si puedes ayudarme tambien con eso, por favor.